# Progress bar for internal links of a WebView in Android Studio

Tags: android, webview

I have a WebView developed with Android Studio. I want to implement a progress bar to appear on every internal page of the WebView.

I show you the code. Although I must clarify that the app already has a progress bar, which fulfills the function of Splash Screen.

What I want is that when opening a link within the WebView a progress bar appears indicating that the page is loading, since when opening a link the user's screen is paralyzed for a few seconds until it loads completely, which It can be annoying to the naked eye.

**PRELIMINARY CODE:**

> MainActivity

```
package com.example.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String ShowOrHideWebViewInitialUse = "show";
    private ProgressBar spinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        spinner = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());

        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
        webview.loadUrl("https://www.example.com");
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        WebView miVisorWeb;
        miVisorWeb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (miVisorWeb.canGoBack()) {
                        miVisorWeb.goBack();
                    } else {
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView webview, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

            if (ShowOrHideWebViewInitialUse.equals("show")) {
                webview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            ShowOrHideWebViewInitialUse = "hide";
            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        }
    }
}
```

It would be a great help if you could implement another progress bar that does not fill the entire screen, that is displayed when loading a link within the WebView and that then disappears when the loading is complete.

***Thank you very much!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a Spinner progress bar, you can use horizontal bar by changing the style.

```
<ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        --- other attributes here ---
         />
```

Place this horizontal progress bar on the top of the webview similar to the image below.

[image: Progress bar mock up]

Additionally, by setting `chromeWebClient` to the webview and overriding `onProgressChanged` method we can get the progress of the page loading which can be set to the horizontal progress bar.

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
       progressBar.setProgressCompat(newProgress, true)
    }
});
```