# Trying to add progress bar in web view in fragment

Tags: android, fragment, progress-bar

i am planning to add a progress bar in  web view in a fragment but i am having many issues. Tried searching a lot about this but nothing worked.
Below is the code i am using for home fragment

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
private WebView webView;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
String value = "https://google.com/";


public HomeFragment() {

    // Required empty public constructor
}

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
    //View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progress);


    if(bundle != null){

        value = getArguments().getString("Key");
        Log.i("Details",value);
        //webView.loadUrl(value);
    }

    webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(value);


    Log.i("Details2",value);
    return rootView;


}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String value) {
        view.loadUrl(value);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(final WebView view, final String value, final Bitmap favicon) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        super.onPageStarted(view, value, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String value) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        super.onPageFinished(view, value);
    }
}
```

}

this code results the light grey line in web view, which remain visible all the time.

[look at the red square in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yOmS.jpg)

Please let me know what wrong i am doing.

Sorry for the bad english or if i am

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62590055/5370569
this might be helpful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Progress bar for internal links of a WebView in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62589346/progress-bar-for-internal-links-of-a-webview-in-android-studio)

Comment: I tried the above code but receiving error on below line 'progressBar.setProgressCompat(newProgress, true);'    cannot resolve method 'setProgressCompat(int, boolean)'

Comment: Do I need to add any dependency ? @Nataraj KR

Comment: `setProgressCompat` is an extension function that I wrote for version check. Just use the method `setProgress(int, boolean)` for versions 'N' and above & `setProgress(int)` for versions below 'N'

Answer (score 0):

refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62590055/5370569

/* extension function */

```
fun ProgressBar.setProgressCompat(progress: Int, animate: Boolean) {
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
      setProgress(progress, animate)
   } else {
      setProgress(progress)
   }
}
```

Comment: `webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                progressBar.setProgress(newProgress, true);
            }
        });`  Using this code but the app stops on startup. I am sorry but i don't know about these extension things. This code of mine is almost 1 year old. I am bit newbie. If you can help me with the whole code it will be amazing, if possible. @Nataraj KR

Comment: can you share the error log... along with your minSdkVersion code... BTW @RequiresApi annotation usage is not correct.

Comment: Attaching the link of image for error log https://i.ibb.co/2j7Jnzx/Capture.png   **Min sdk version is 15**  Also i am describing what i did. I replaced this whole class  `private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient` with your class `webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()` as in previous comment and facing this error.  @RequiresApi annotation was auto completed. @Nataraj KR

Comment: WebViewClient and WebChromeClient are different so do not replace them. Instead, add WebChromeClient alongside the WebViewClient. Also, a suggestion update progressBar in the `onViewCreated` method of Fragment instead of in `onCreateView` method.

Comment: 1. Replaced `onCreateView` to `onViewCreated` 
2. Using code referred in 1st comment with `progressBar.setProgress(newProgress, true);`
3. Using both classes `private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient`&  `webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()`
4. Error using `onViewCreated`– app open & white screen, Error log https://i.ibb.co/mzrxS6K/Capture6.png
Error using `onCreateView` - app crash, Error log https://i.ibb.co/7nwGnmt/Capture7.png
**Code image**
1.https://i.ibb.co/D9vGn60/Capture.png
2.https://i.ibb.co/XJ0Pf3B/Capture2.png
3.https://i.ibb.co/qprfmJs/Capture5.png

Comment: Above are the steps i have tried or using. The best i can with the comment word limit. I know its bit difficult to understand. Let me know  if you need any other information or clarification. Thank you so much giving your precious time. @Nataraj KR

Comment: inflate the view in `onCreateView` method and make sure only post view inflation code stays in `onViewCreated` method

Comment: I suggest you read docs for the respective methods.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#lifecycle

Comment: I am sorry but i didn't understand much. What i got is, i have to use `onViewCreated` method after `onCreateView`. So i created method `public void onViewCreated (View view, 
         Bundle savedInstanceState)` but don't know what to put inside. I tried `class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient` inside this method but app still crash. I know i am not good at coding but i really need this for my first own app for my website. It will amazing if you can help me the whole code of this fragment if possible then i will mange for other 4 fragments. Again thanks for your precious time.@Nataraj KR

Comment: I would like to add that the class `private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {` says private inner class `MyWebViewClient` is never used. Also if i don't use the code your referred in the first comment the app opens without crash but progress bar stuck on the top and does nothing (Because of the error  "class never used"). Hope this helps to gather more information about the issue.@Nataraj KR

Comment: this might help
https://gist.github.com/natarajkr007/21f19b29ff9c23e2796ef8cccd8830ce

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. I used that code but still some issues appearing. Private inner class `MyWebViewClient` is never used. I tried some googling but failed. https://i.ibb.co/rbZKrpq/Capture6.png
This seems to be the reason behind the progressbar not working. **I tried the code after some minor changes but the result were same. Progressbar was appearing all the time but doing nothing at the top of app.**
onCreate method was asking for super.onCreate I did https://i.ibb.co/JzzbnNx/Capture7.png
Some errors with variables here. https://i.ibb.co/12nNhyd/Capture.png   @Nataraj KR